# I can't use fs.readFile function in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, fs

I'm using electron for app development. But when I use fs.readFile function 
electron throw error.

Code:

```
fs.readFile('data.json',(err,data)=>{
  console.log(data);
  win.webContents.send('data:load',JSON.parse(data.toString()));
})
```

Output:

```
{}
null
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle exception `err` to check the error detail of `fs.readFile()` reading file properly or not, usually it is file not found following file path:

```js
fs.readFile('data.json',(err,data)=>{
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
    win.webContents.send('data:load',JSON.parse(data.toString()));
})
```